# pg_restore on table failing because of hstore

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pg-restore

**Background**:

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.

After a bad script, I have a table that I need to restore from a dump file created via pg_dump.  On this table, I have an audit trigger that is based on 
this [wiki page.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) As you can see, the trigger function uses an hstore.

**Error**:

When I attempt the restore, I get:

```
$ pg_restore -a --dbname=a193 -Fc --host=localhost --port=5434 --username=postgres -W --table=foo ~/tmp/a193.dump
Password: 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4600; 0 26146 TABLE DATA foo u2su8s81ul0a52
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "foo": ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist
LINE 6:     h_old hstore;
```

The extension definitely does exist.

```
=> \dx
                                        List of installed extensions
+--------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|        Name        | Version |   Schema   |                         Description                          |
+--------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| dblink             | 1.1     | public     | connect to other PostgreSQL databases from within a database |
| hstore             | 1.2     | public     | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs             |
| isn                | 1.0     | public     | data types for international product numbering standards     |
| pg_stat_statements | 1.1     | public     | track execution statistics of all SQL statements executed    |
| pgcrypto           | 1.0     | public     | cryptographic functions                                      |
| plpgsql            | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language                                 |
| plpythonu          | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/PythonU untrusted procedural language                     |
| postgres_fdw       | 1.0     | public     | foreign-data wrapper for remote PostgreSQL servers           |
| uuid-ossp          | 1.0     | public     | generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs)              |
+--------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
(9 rows)
```

And I can use it in a query (as the postgres user - the same role as I'm using above for the restore):

```
=> select current_user;
+--------------+
| current_user |
+--------------+
| postgres     |
+--------------+
(1 row)

=> \du
                                 List of roles
+----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|   Role name    |                   Attributes                   | Member of |
+----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| postgres       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}        |
| u2su8s81ul0a52 |                                                | {}        |
+----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------+

=> select 'a=>1'::hstore;
+----------+
|  hstore  |
+----------+
| "a"=>"1" |
+----------+
(1 row)
```

**Questions:**

1. Why am I getting this error when the database has this extension installed?
2. Other than dropping the trigger, how can I get around this issue? Dropping trigger is not the worse thing in the world, but it seems like this should be possible and in a production database, I'd like to be able to see the audit trail that someone did a restore of the data, etc.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that hstore isn't in the "search_path" for user postgres, but is for whoever you log in to check. Try restoring to data to a file rather than direct to the DB and take a look at the SQL if you want to check.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I've updated my OP to include the information about what user I'm logged as when I do the select as (which is postgres).

Comment: Well either you've changed the default prompt or you've taken superuser rights away from "postgres" because that's the wrong prompt for a superuser.

Comment: I've changed the default prompt in .psqlrc

Comment: In which schema is the table you are trying to restore? pg_dump changes the search_path at beginning of the dump with SET search_pach=.... but does not take care of the types which are used from the tables (pg_dump bug?). If your dump is in plain text, give a look with a text editor.

Comment: I'm running into the same exact issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218855/pg-restore-certain-tables-only). It appears to only happen when the `-t`/`--table` flag is set.

Comment: @Tommaso. I'm not sure how this would be a search_path issue (but, maybe it is). As you can see above, hstore is installed into public. And I've confirmed public is in the search path. The backup is failing on an auditing trigger function (which uses hstore).  This trigger is in the audit schema - which is always on the search path. The dump was created with -Fc option, so it is not text. And I don't think it is possible to do a single table restore from a plain text dump.

Comment: @David, my question was, in which schema is the table, not the trigger or hstore. Glad you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in either pg_dump or pg_restore. Per Richard Huxton's suggestion above I restored to a file.

```
pg_restore --data-only --table=foo -f ~/tmp/foo.sql ~/tmp/a193.dump
```

When I looked at the contents, I found that it was doing the following at the top:

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET search_path = myschema, pg_catalog;
```

Running this line from inside of psql with `\i` still fails, but editing the last line to include the public schema (which is where hstore is installed) works.

```
SET search_path = myschema, pg_catalog, public;
```

I'm then able to run from inside psql with `\i` and import the lost data.

Comment: I don't know for sure but it seems its not actually a bug but a very big gotcha about the way `search_path` is working. See: https://www.postgresonline.com/article_pfriendly/279.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with two functions (`checksum` and `is_valid`) and a table (`master_values`) defined in public. Here `checksum` was calling `is_valid` and `master_values` had a check-constraint:

```
"master_values_master_id_check" CHECK(is_valid(master_id))"
```

Note that there was no `search_path` or schema-reference used in any of these.

When trying to restore the dump I got this during the restore:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "master_values": ERROR:  function checksum(integer) does not exist
```

The strange thing is that after the restore both functions and the table are there and works as expected. **The only thing missing is the data in `master_values` that did not get restored.**

This was solved by specifying the `search_path` for `is_valid`:

```
ALTER FUNCTION is_valid SET search_path = public;
```

For more info on this see:

- The docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterfunction.html
- Article1: https://www.postgresonline.com/article_pfriendly/279.html
- Article2: https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2012/11/15/postgresql-searchpath-behaviour

Comment: Note that the link to Article2 mentioned here has moved to: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2012/11/postgresql-searchpath-behaviour/