# pg_restore certain tables only

Tags: postgresql, hstore, pg-restore

I'm trying to write a `pg_restore` command to restore only certain tables (and their data) to my database.

**Note: every command described begins with me dropping and re-creating the database and ends in: `-v -x -O -j 8 -h localhost -U username -d database file.dump`** (For the curious, I didn't want to use `--clean` because the database that the dump came from has a different name.)

Since `pg_restore` works fine for me (with the above args), I looked at the [`pg_restore` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html), and tried something like this:

`pg_restore -t table1 -t table2 ...` (there are 121 tables I specify in this way).

However, I get errors like the following:

```
pg_restore: creating TABLE people
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 123; 1234 12345 TABLE people dumped_table_username
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist
LINE 14:     extra_data hstore,
                        ^
    Command was: CREATE TABLE people (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name string,
    age integer,
    date_of_birt...
```

I don't see why this would be an issue only when the `-t` flag is set, but it appears to be.

What's going on?

---

**Edit:** looks like this is a duplicate of [pg_restore on table failing because of hstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200164/pg-restore-on-table-failing-because-of-hstore), which was recently asked and has no accepted answer as of this time.

Comment: `... begins with me dropping and re-creating the database and ends in ...` You mean "dropping and recreating the *table*" ?

Comment: Nope, I mean the entire database. I'm using Rails, so `rake db:drop && rake db:create`.

Comment: Well if you drop the *database* then the `hstore` extension is dropped as well. Do you run `create extension hstore` after you re-created the database (and before you restore your dump)?

Comment: I thought the restore would take care of that, since it does so for whole-database restores (i.e. `pg_restore` without the `-t` flag) and the dump file includes `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore WITH SCHEMA public;`. Apparently not though. Adding a `psql database -c "CREATE EXTENSION hstore;"` call before the `pg_restore` fixes this.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `pg_restore` with the `-t`/`--table` flag set doesn't run `CREATE EXTENSION` commands that are in the dump file (because they're not technically part of that table). My problem was solved by manually running `psql database -c "CREATE EXTENSION hstore;"` before the `pg_restore` command.

Comment: If you are doing that on a regular basis, you might want to create the hstore extension in the template1 database. That way each new database automatically has the hstore extension installed.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that! If you make that an answer I'll accept it.